# window.innerHeight consistent between Chrome's baked in UI elements

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm sure this is the working as intended, but I find it kind of a pain.

In Chrome (and probably other browsers)

Generally, `window.innerHeight` gives me 801 (for example).

If I have a console open along the bottom half of my screen (going horizontally), this changes my window.innerHeight. If I've downloaded something, this pops up a bar at the bottom of the window and also changes window.innerHeight.

I don't having the dev tools open to make my site feel broken.

Is there a different measurement to use in javascript to ignore UI?

I don't want outerWidth, because this includes window tab heights and they won't be consistent cross browser.

I essentially want the height to be consistent whether or not there are any chrome ui elements present.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get exactly that number! The closest you can get is calculating the available height, minus os taskbar and such by using:

```
window.screen.availHeight
```

Which MDN says:

> Returns the amount of vertical space available to the window on the
>   screen.

I made a jsfiddle to try it in [here](https://jsfiddle.net/omidfi/234tfgmg/)

[MDN availHeight article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/availHeight)

Comment: is this not pretty much window.outerHeight?

Comment: outerHeight yields the same as availHeight see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/234tfgmg/1/

Comment: Not always! If you resize the browser window, the outer height changes, but availHeight stays the same!

Comment: outerHeight will change though depending on if they use additional toolbars? and cut down on innerheight

Comment: as far as I see, outerHeight is current window size, so all the browser toolbars are included.